# Windows 10 Enable Peek doesn't enable peek

Tags: windows-10

I have enabled the "Peek" effect in the Performance settings but it is still not enabled.

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with that Setting enabled (checked) as it is, also enable Peek in Windows 10 Task Bar settings.

Please refer to the Screen Shot below. I have Peek disabled on this machine.

[image]

I do not recommend registry changes for easy user actions. Windows may change this down the road and keep only the easy user actions.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't see that setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable through registry.

First go to the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and create a new REG_DWORD Value named `DisablePreviewDesktop` and set its value to 0.

Then go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM` and create a new REG_DWORD value named `EnableAeroPeek` and set its value to 1.

Then either restart Explorer or Log off and log on.